# AWS EC2 IAM Permissions Don't Show any Available Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm using the following set of IAM permissions for my AWS account.  The goal is to allow our developers access to any "development" resources...launching from our AMIs, starting instances, stopping them, etc.  As such, we've tagged the volume snapshots and the AMIs themselves.  However, when I log in with a developer account in the group, I'm unable to see anything that was tagged and therefore can't do anything.  Any help would be much appreciated...thanks!

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Purpose": "Development"
                },
                "DateLessThan": {
                    "aws:CurrentTime": "2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT: I should add that I'm trying to enable them to do this through the console, not the CLI or via the SDK.